# Spring MVC disable caching for resource .js files

Tags: spring-mvc

We have a bunch of .js files in a web application which are not located under a single directory. UI was developed separately and it is pretty time consuming to redesign it to have all the *.js files in one place.

The problem is that those files are cached by browsers pretty heavily and this creates a lot of issues with every application update. And we decided to turn off caching for those files.

So, *.js files were included into servlet mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have tried using mvc:resources  but it does not handle url's masks like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="*.js" location="*.js" cache-period="0"/>
```

This doesn't work and I have 404 response back when I am trying to access a js file.

I have also tried mvc:interceptor:

```
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="*.js"/>
        <bean id="webJSContentInterceptor"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
```

This results in 404 error as well.

Is this type of thing possible?

Comment: Caching of JS files is a known issue and your suggested ideas above will not solve this problem completely. You want JS files to be cached most of the time (client performance matters) except when you change and deploy a new version. Cache busting is the best solution - usually by adding a version number to the path (or adding a useless request parameter) of each static JS/CSS file, which changes with each new deployed version (and thus forces browser to grab the new version). I've found JAWR to be a good solution for this (no need to reinvent the wheel) - http://jawr.java.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. But there are several options:

- Implement a custom Filter, map it to *.js mask and set needed headers from there.
- Handle cache busting in JavaScript. We went this way and added a version number to the path of our JS files.

Answer (score 6):

I realize this answer comes rather late, but here's for future reference.

### Serving static resources with ResourceHttpRequestHandlers (Spring 3.2+)

First, you were on the right track with `<mvc:resources>`, there was just a typo in your path pattern declaration:

- the `location` must be a folder location where you resources live (this can be on your file system, in your webapp resources, on the classpath, in webJARs...)
- the pattern must take into account your project layout

Let's say you've got the following structure:

```
src/main/webapp/static/
  |- js/
  |- js/lib/jquery.js
  |- js/main.js
  |- css/style.css
```

You can serve all your static resources like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/static/"/>
```

Note: `cache-period` and other attributes should work just fine.

### Resource handling features (Spring 4.1+)

As of Spring 4.1, there are new, more flexible ways to work with this.

For example, you can achieve cache busting with your JS and CSS files like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/static/"/>
  <mvc:resource-chain resource-cache="true">
    <mvc:resolvers>
      <mvc:version-resolver>
        <mvc:content-version-strategy patterns="/**"/>
      </mvc:version-resolver>
    </mvc:resolvers>
  </mvc:resource-chain>
</mvc:resources>
```

Of course you can achieve the same thing (more elegantly) with javaconfig:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

  VersionResourceResolver versionResolver = new VersionResourceResolver()
    .addContentVersionStrategy("/**");

  registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
    .addResourceLocations(/static/)
    .resourceChain(true).addResolver(versionResolver);
}
```

See this [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/24/spring-framework-4-1-handling-static-web-resources) and [this example app](https://github.com/bclozel/spring-resource-handling) for more on this.

Answer (score 0):

According to me the problem is your JS files are not getting loaded.
In the second approach you have tried you have not specified the value of **path** attribute correctly. Mapping is proper but in place of the path you need to specify the exact location from root where your JS files are.

Try to do that. Hope this helps you.